# Excel if function pulling multiple values from a table

Tags: excel-formula

Apologies if my question's wording is not the best. I am trying to devise a simple formula, as follows:

The cost of some items we sell is based on availability, which is determined from a table. The table has lines and columns each of them going from 1 to 9. The cells are each filled with a cost.

So for example, imagine an item is given a value of 38. To get the price, you could look at line 3 and column 8, and the matching cell gives you the price.

How do I devise a formula, wherein if I input the availability value (say 38) in a cell, it would look for the matching price from line 3, column 8)

Furthermore, there are some taxes to be added which vary based on the location the item is bought. For example Atlanta would attract a 12% tax etc...

So I was thinking of adding a couple of extra cell, the first one in which you'd type the city, and then I'd have a separate table on the spreadsheet with the list of cities and the matching taxes. So I would want to add a second formula, that would take the cost and add the matching taxes based on the city the user has type.

Thanks and sorry if not very clear

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your explanation, but I think you can use vlookup. Or, you can put some of your actual data [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c7qyNLoC3zxgTqCfmlB6HoRwBwHmjB6Q057BLNYj6Z0/edit?usp=sharing) by making new sheets for you, so I can help.

Comment: If there is only one potential outcome then as @anakpanti has stated, VLOOKUP will work. If there's more than 1 potential outcome it gets a bit tricky and requires the advanced use of INDEX, MATCH and SMALL. I'd advise 2 VLOOKUP formulas one for availability value and the other for tax amount. Give it a try and if you get stuck edit in the formula you have tried and i'll give you a hand.

Comment: give me a hand?! I'm in the position who willingly give you a hand here. well... i know this is your first post, but isn't you making a hard time for me or anyone here who want to help you? I just ask you to copy/write some of your data, so I just need to make and think the formula. But here you go, making me make my own data and provide the formula for you. haha. But It's okay since this is your first post. I will post my answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the answer [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c7qyNLoC3zxgTqCfmlB6HoRwBwHmjB6Q057BLNYj6Z0/edit?usp=sharing) in **sheet "data"**

You can hide the unnecessary column. I'm adding some columns, so the formula for the final result won't be too long and too hard to understand.

well.... `final result = value + (value * %tax)`

you can easily change the formula if I'm wrong.

I use vlookup to find column name based on number and taxes based on country name.

Answer (score 0):

Refering to the attached image:

- Product data is A1:E5
- City tax information is A8:B12
- The entered/calculated information is G8:M12

The functions are:

- J1: `=VLOOKUP(VALUE(LEFT(H9,1)),$A$1:$E$5,MATCH(VALUE(RIGHT(H9,1)),$A$1:$E$1,0),0)`
- K1: `=VLOOKUP(I9,$A$8:$B$12,2,0)`
- L1: `=K9*J9`
- M1: `=L9+J9`

The VLOOKUP() formula allows you to select a certain row based on value, then pick the nth column. So basically, it uses the leftmost digit of "Product ID" to pick which row to use. For the nth column, the MATCH() formula returns the position for a certain value. Here we use the rightmost digit of "Product ID" to calculate the nth column.

For the Tax rate it's more simple. It also VLOOKUP() picking the row based on "City", then returns the value in the 2nd column.

I see only one problem here. You are limited in the product IDs to only two digit numbers - this will be split into 1 digit for the columns, and 1 digit for the rows. This can easily be overcome by modifying either RIGHT() or LEFT() formulas embedded within J1 formula.

Hope this helps.

[Excel Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5lWJ.png)